# canvasJS Insert new datapoint by directly passing an object

Tags: javascript, class, canvasjs

So,

I'm getting an object containing the data i want to graph in this form(by Json) in the following form:

```
chartData(GraphData.year, GraphData.month, GraphData.day, GraphData.hour, GraphData.minute, GraphData.y, GraphData.indexLabel, GraphData.markerColor, GraphData.markerType))
```

So basicly i have:

```
chartData{year:2017, month:11, day:2, hour:10, y: 21 , indexLabel: "Pump 1 On", markerColor: "green", markerType: "triangle" }
```

but canvasJS needs them to be like:

```
chartData{ x: new Date(1987,03,25, 08, 39), y: 658 , indexLabel: "Pump 1 On", markerColor: "green", markerType: "triangle" }
```

How can i transform my object to the required form?
In short what the constructor of chartData class should look like?
Also i want to want to add multiple of theese object in an array like

```
dailyGraphData.push(new chartData);
```

(Of course im updating chartData object before pushing it into the dailyGraphData array)

TY in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, for future reference

```
class chartTempData {
  constructor(year, month, day, hour, minute, levelCM, indexLabel, markerColor, markerType) {
    this.year = year;
    this.month = month;
    this.day = day;
    this.hour = hour;
    this.minute = minute;
    this.levelCM = levelCM;
    this.indexLabel = indexLabel;
    this.markerColor = markerColor;
    this.markerType = markerType;
  }
}



class chartData {
          constructor(date, y, indexLabel, markerColor, markerType) {
            this.x = date;
            this.y = y;
            this.indexLabel = indexLabel;
            this.markerColor = markerColor;
            this.markerType = markerType;
          }
        }


        var dailyGraphData = new Array();
//The following line is just for test purpuse, normaly these values are asigned by incomming JSON data
        var dailyTempGraphData = new chartTempData(2017, 11, 2, 08, 13, 25, "Pump 1 On", "green", "triangle");  //incomming data is firstly stored here element by element then stored in the regular array en mase




        function transferDataToArray()
        {
            var dailyGraphDataArrayLength=0;
            dailyGraphDataArrayLength = dailyGraphData.push(new chartData(new Date(dailyTempGraphData.year, dailyTempGraphData.month, dailyTempGraphData.day, dailyTempGraphData.hour, dailyTempGraphData.minute), dailyTempGraphData.levelCM, dailyTempGraphData.indexLabel, dailyTempGraphData.markerColor, dailyTempGraphData.markerType));
            dailyGraphDataArrayLength = dailyGraphData.push(new chartData(new Date(dailyTempGraphData.year, dailyTempGraphData.month, dailyTempGraphData.day, dailyTempGraphData.hour+2, dailyTempGraphData.minute+15), dailyTempGraphData.levelCM+14, "Hollo worls", "purple", "cross"));
            console.log(dailyGraphDataArrayLength);
            console.log(dailyGraphData[0]);
            console.log(dailyTempGraphData);
            chart.render();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are practically answering this question yourself.. remember you just need a text file and a browser to test some of these things out..

for example taking two pieces of what you have posted.. what does this do:

```
dailyGraphData.push({year:2017, month:11, day:2, hour:10, y: 21 , indexLabel: "Pump 1 On", markerColor: "green", markerType: "triangle" });
```

And if that works all you need is the data from your other object.. how might you combine that?

well you could have a method on a class or a stand alone function i guess:

```
function mapData(graphData){
     return { year: graphData.year, month:graphData.month ...... };
}
```

then combine that:

```
dailyGraphData.push(mapData(firstFormat));
```

for testing make sure you are comfortable with console.log and JSON.stringify and your browsers developer tools so that you can investigate what is going on - if you know how to use these tools then try some more stuff and post failing code when asking a questions.